# How can I Parser file without giving file name in Perl?

Tags: perl, parsing, html-parsing, html-lists, token

When I run the programme at that time I only give a directory name I want all files in the directory to be parsed? Here is my code

```
my @indexFiles= "www/I.html";
my @rdata = readFile("@indexFiles");
sub readFile{
  my $somefile = $_[0];
  my @links = ($somefile);
  my $p = HTML::TokeParser->new($somefile) || die "Can't open: $!";
  while (my $token = $p->get_tag("img","a")){
     my $currentlink = $token->[1]{href} || $token->[1]{src};
     my $finalLink= $directory."/".$currentlink ; 
     if($currentlink =~ /\.html$/){
         my @data = readFile($finalLink);  
         push @links,@data;
     } else{
          push @links,$finalLink;
     }
  }
  return @links;
}
```

In `www` folder I have 3 HTML file, 2 folder.

`my @indexFiles= "www/I.html"` In this line I pass specific path name and file. I don't want to pass that name. Instead of this, it will select automatically.

For example: When I run my programme `perl c.pl www`. It should be Parse all the file. 
I give the specific file name `I.html` then after it will be going to find img and a tag.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for

Comment: It seems like you are trying to give a filename to `HTML::TokeParser`. Please clarify what you are trying to do? Why do you want call it without a filename?

Comment: @HåkonHægland I want because in some another folder whatever .html file are there my programme should be run. for that folder.

Comment: @ikegami I am going to ask how can I parse file without giving file specific file name?

Comment: So sometimes you give a filename, and sometimes you give a directory name? And when you give a directory name you want all files in the directory to be parsed?

Comment: @mob yes exactly.

Comment: So you're question has nothing to do with parsing or HTML::TokeParser, and is actually about determining whether a path references a directory or not, and getting the list of files in the directory if it references a directory? If I'm correct, could you please edit your post to ask your actual question?

Comment: @ikegami In the first line, I give the file name. then my programme will start to parse that file and all other files. But my question is I don't want to pass that file name. If I run my programme only with directory then it should be automatically select all the .html file and need to start parsing.

Comment: @ikegami if you see the "mob" comment. you will understand.

Comment: You need to write code that determines whether it was given a filename or a directory name, and then act accordingly. If it's a directory, find all the HTML files, then process them. If it's a file, process just that file. As ikegami says, it's irrelevant to the question what you actually do with those files.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't appear to have anything to do with parsing or HTML::TokeParser; it appears to be about determining whether a path references a directory or not, and getting the list of files in the directory if it references a directory.

[`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) and [`-d`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) (in conjunction or independently) can be used to test if a path references a directory.

At the lowest level, [`opendir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html)+[`readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html)+[`closedir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/closedir.html) is used to read a directory. The [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) builtin and numerous modules provide alternatives ways of doing this.

Recursive search:

```
sub process {
   for my $qfn (@_) {
      stat($qfn)
         or die("Can't stat \"$qfn\": $!\n");

       if (-d _) {
          process(glob("\Q$qfn\E/*"));
       }
       elsif ($qfn =~ /\.html\z/) {
          process_html_file($qfn);
       }
   }
}

process('www');
```

Non-recursive search:

```
sub process {
   for my $qfn (@_) {
      stat($qfn)
         or die("Can't stat \"$qfn\": $!\n");

       if (-d _) {
          process_html_file(glob("\Q$qfn\E/*.html"));
       }
       elsif ($qfn =~ /\.html\z/) {
          process_html_file($qfn);
       }
   }
}

process('www');
```

Alternatively, you could use [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule).

Recursive search:

```
use File::Find::Rule qw( );

process_html_file($_)
   for File::Find::Rule->name('*.html')->file->in('www');
```

Non-recursive search:

```
use File::Find::Rule qw( );

process_html_file($_)
   for File::Find::Rule->maxdepth(1)->name('*.html')->file->in('www');
```